# How to prevent a conditional in a template literal from rendering false

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I have the following template literal

```
`<div class="date ${($.inArray(date, dates) == -1) && `outside`}">
     <div>${date.format('D')}</div>
 </div>`
```

When the expression `($.inArray(date, dates) == -1)` evaluates to true, the class outside shows up and nothing else, however, when it evaluates to false, false is outputted as a result of `${($.inArray(date, dates) == -1) &&`outside`}`.

How could I avoid outputting false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator): `condition ? valueWhenTrue : valueWhenFalse`:

```
`<div class="date ${($.inArray(date, dates) == -1) ? `outside` : ``}">
    <div>${date.format('D')}</div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator:

```
($.inArray(date, dates) == -1) ? 'outside' : ''
```

Fallback to empty string:

```
($.inArray(date, dates) == -1) && 'outside' || ''
```